# 500 internal server error on hidden __viewstate of asp.net page

Tags: c#, .net, client-server, cross-domain

I am trying to post the data to cross domain. It works fine if the form is not using runat="server" and its giving 500 internal error while posting when the form is using runat="server".

Upon debugging, I identified that the problem is with auto generated __viewstate code on the page. Please find the below code.

### Clientside HTML implementation:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="Sample.aspx.cs" Inherits="Sample" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link href="FileUpload.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

   <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
    </script>
    <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
    </script>

    <script src="../../test/FileUpload/jQueryv1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="fileupload-js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="fileupload-js/tmpl.min.js"></script>
    <script src="fileupload-js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
    <script src="fileupload-js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="fileupload-js/locale.js"></script>
    <script src="fileupload-js/main.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
<form id="fileupload" method="POST" runat="server">
    <CCAB.Web:FileUpload runat="server"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Serverside code:

```
public partial class SaveFile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

        if (Request.HttpMethod == "GET" || Request.HttpMethod == "HEAD")
        {

            Response.Write("GET Success");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                string filename = Request.Files[i].FileName;
                Request.Files[i].SaveAs(@"\\dev2\\share$\\Anna\\test\\" + filename);
                Response.Write(filename);
            Response.Write("Success");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Could you please help me in how to ignore the hidden viewstate code from client side or ignore the response viewstate in server side.

Many Thanks
Anna

Comment: I think the problem is with the Validation of viewstate MAC. since the client side view state mac is not matching with the server side view state mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this problem. Please find below

```
public class BasePage : Page

{

  private static string[] aspNetFormElements = new string[] 

  { 

    "__EVENTTARGET",

    "__EVENTARGUMENT",

    "__VIEWSTATE",

    "__EVENTVALIDATION",

    "__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED",

  };



  protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)

  {

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

    base.Render(htmlWriter);

    string html = stringWriter.ToString();

    int formStart = html.IndexOf("<form");

    int endForm = -1;

    if (formStart >= 0)

      endForm = html.IndexOf(">", formStart);



    if (endForm >= 0)

    {

      StringBuilder viewStateBuilder = new StringBuilder();

      foreach (string element in aspNetFormElements)

      {

        int startPoint = html.IndexOf("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + element + "\"");

        if (startPoint >= 0 && startPoint > endForm)

        {

          int endPoint = html.IndexOf("/>", startPoint);

          if (endPoint >= 0)

          {

            endPoint += 2;

            string viewStateInput = html.Substring(startPoint, endPoint - startPoint);

            html = html.Remove(startPoint, endPoint - startPoint);

            viewStateBuilder.Append(viewStateInput).Append("\r\n");

          }

        }

      }



      if (viewStateBuilder.Length > 0)

      {

        viewStateBuilder.Insert(0, "\r\n");

        html = html.Insert(endForm + 1, viewStateBuilder.ToString());

      }

    }



    writer.Write(html);

  }

}
```

Please find more info on this page : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error.aspx

Many Thanks
Anna

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling view state by adding a line of code to your unload handler:

```
Page.EnableViewState = false;
```

see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstate.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I got it.